# How to add the list elements in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

for example I have a list with numbers like this:

```
a = [10,[20,30],40]
```

or

```
b = [[10,20],30]
```

Now I have to add all the elements in the above lists.
so that if add the first list then I should get the answer as follows: `10+20+30+40 = 100`.
and for the second one b as follows: `10+20+30 = 60`.
The solution is to be expressed as a function.
I have tried this one but it can be used for only adding if there is no nested list.

```
def sum(t):
    total = 0
    for x in t:
        total = total+x
    return total
```

Now can anyone help me solve this kind of problem in python programming.
Thank you in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use *reduce*:

```
x = reduce(lambda prev,el: prev+([x for x in el] if type(el) is list else [el]), x, [])
```

And use its result to feed your loop.

```
def sum(t):
    t = reduce(lambda prev,el: prev+([x for x in el] if type(el) is list else [el]), t, [])
    total = 0
    for x in t:
        total = total+x
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the best approach would be to iterate over the top-level list and check each element's type (using `is_instance(type, item)`). If it's an integer, add it to the total, otherwise if it's a list, iterate over that list.

Making your function recursive would make it most usable.

---

**Edit:** For anybody stumbling upon this question, here's an example.

```
def nested_sum(input_list):
    total = 0
    for element in input_list:
        if isinstance(element, int):
            total += element
        elif isinstance(element, list):
            total += nested_sum(element)
        else:
            raise TypeError

    return total
```

Usage:

```
my_list = [72, 5, [108, 99, [8, 5], 23], 44]
print nested_sum(my_list)
>>> 364
```

Comment: Can you please write the code for that...

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively flatten into a single list:

```
def flatten(lst, out=None):
    if out is None:
        out = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            flatten(item, out)
        else:
            out.append(item)
    return out
```

Now you can just use `sum`:

```
>>> sum(flatten([10, [20, 30], 40]))
100
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a recursion to handle the nested lists:

```
rec = lambda x: sum(map(rec, x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x
```

`rec`, applied on a list, will return the sum (recursively), on a value, return the value.

```
result = rec(a)
```